# Directshow vcam start on connection

Tags: video, directshow

Poking around at Vivek's vcam of directshow [Capture Source Filter](http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm):

> A sample source filter that emulates a video capture device contributed by Vivek (rep movsd from the public newsgroups).

Is it possible to configure this to start at the beginning of the virtual camera stream when a program begins consuming the vcam source.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual camera receives various commands and requests from controlling application: when it is added to graph, when it is set up, when connected within the pipeline, when set to pause, to run. You are free to handle that the way you like.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a closer look, just got vcam building.